# Regex URL dispatching

Tags: php, regex

I am building a REST API in PHP and I need some help with the following regex that will handle the parsing of these urls:

```
https://api.mine.com/mine&id=5/comment&id=3
https://api.mine.com/user&username=rick&email=rick@rick.com/friend&id=3
```

So in the url: /mine&id=5/comment&id=3

We want to get the nested parameters & value's so eventually we get this array:

mine => 'id': 5,
comment => 'id': 3

What regex could I use to get this algorithm that also supports multiple parameters?

Thanks alot.

Comment: Are you certain that regexps is really what you want to be doing? I think I'd follow an approach that takes the output of `parse_url()` and then splits the query fragment – `explode('&',$query)` to get the array you need.

Comment: If you advocate `parse_url`, I would also advocate `parse_str` ;)

Comment: these are odd urls. They dont like very HTTPish, nor particularly RESTtful

Comment: Since you're building the API yourself, why are you using such an obscure syntax? I urge you to reconsider your design and read [REST-ful URI design](http://redrata.com/restful-uri-design/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
$pattern = "\/(.*?)\&(.*?)=(.*?)\/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $url, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```